# How do i create a drop down menu in modx

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, menu, modx

Hey guys I'm wondering how would I be able to create a drop down menu under my career's tab in modx and attach a page to it ?

my current menu code is

```
<!-- Start Navigation List -->
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li id="menu_active"><a href="[[~1]]">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="[[~2]]">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="[[~3]]">Our Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="[[~4]]">Our Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="[[~6]]">Testimonials</a></li>
    <li><a href="[[~11]]">Careers</a></li>
    <li><a href="[[~5]]">Contact Us</a></li>
<!-- End Navigation List -->
```

any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want your navigation to be dynamically generated, you'll need to use [WayFinder](https://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/wayfinder). It will also help handle the "active" class and things like that.

To create the actual drop-down functionality, you'll need something like [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/examples/).

**TL;DR**: Use Wayfinder to *build* the markup, use Superfish to bring it to life.